# Solving $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{n^a}{\log\left(\left| \log(n^a)\right|\right)}}$

Tags: limits

I haven't practiced limits for years, now I need them to solve an exercise and I don't know whether I have come up with the right solution.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{n^a}{\log\left(\left| \log(n^a)\right|\right)}}$$

where $a$ is a fixed constant.

Since I have the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, I apply the De L'Hopital theorem, so I derive both numerator and denominator, so:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{an^{a-1}}{\frac{a}{n\log(n^a)}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{n\log(n^a)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{a n\log(n)} = \infty$$

Can you please give me any feedback?

Comment: You're doing wrong with the derivative of the denominator. Rewrite it as $\log|a|+\log\log n$ (for $a\ne0$; but the expression is undefined for $a=0$).

Comment: So basically I am back to square one with $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, shall I derive again?

Comment: I meant: $\log(|\log(n^a)|)=\log|a|+\log\log n$; apply l'Hôpital to $\dfrac{n^a}{\log|a|+\log\log n}$, which is much easier. But it's not necessarily $\infty/\infty$, do you see why?

Comment: $\dfrac{n^a}{\log|a|+\log\log n} = \dfrac{an^a}{\log(n)}$, there must be something I am missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is defined only for $a\ne0$, because for $a=0$ the denominator would have $\log 0$.

So, assume $a>0$; then you can rewrite the denominator as
$$
\log(|\log n^a|)=\log(|a\log n|)=\log(|a|\log n)=\log|a|+\log\log n
$$
(at least for $n>1$, which is implied).

Since both numerator and denominator go to infinity, you can apply l'Hôpital's theorem:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^a}{\log|a|+\log\log n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{an^{a-1}}{\frac{1}{\log n}\frac{1}{n}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}an^{a-1}\cdot n\log n=
\lim_{n\to\infty}an^a\log n
$$
provided this last limit exists. Does it?

Don't forget to apply the chain rule when differentiating $\log\log n$.

For $a<0$ you have a slightly different, but easier, situation.